# "Find" as a transitive verb

Tags: pronouns, transitive-verbs, complements

I know that in this example

> I find it quite hard to do something

the verb "to find" must be followed by the pronoun "it".  But what if I say

> One thing I found "it" to get used to doing is…

Shall I use "it" in this phrase? as I'm saying "One thing" first so, which one is correct?

1. One thing I found it hard to get used to doing…
2. One thing I found hard to get used to doing…

**Just to give more details as this was actually a kind of an indirect question i was asked**
*" (tell me) One thing you find/found it hard / difficult to get used to doing."*
Let's say the question above was the original sentence . But the "one thing" phrase I found "it " difficult to understand and i took it as the direct object.

Answer (score 2):

The meanings are different. At Google Books:

["One thing I found **it** hard to"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20hard%20to%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20it%20hard%20to%22)

About 31 results

See:

> [Sing, Whisper, Shout, Pray!: Feminist Visions for a Just World](https://books.google.ca/books?id=M2S5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20it%20hard%20to%22&dq=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20it%20hard%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BqgTVZbqJMieoQSXpYDIDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ)-
>   Page 570 M. Jacqui Alexander - 2003 - ‎Snippet view - ‎More editions
>
> But **one thing I found it hard to be generous about** was that
>   Cornelia's mother never offered me anything to eat

This is where **the whole situation** that requires quite a description

"**the whole situation about Cornelia's mother never offering her anything to eat**"

was difficult to cope with.

On the other side, **without "it"**:

["One thing I found hard to"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20hard%20to%22)

About 63 results

E.g.

> [Octavius Mint and the Indigo Dragon: The adventures of an ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=m6a-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20hard%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sakTVbP8LNjXoASS6YGIAg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22One%20thing%20I%20found%20hard%20to%22&f=false)
>   William Stafford - 2013 - ‎Preview - ‎More editions
>
> This idea was **one thing I found hard to** swallow.

Here the **thing/idea itself** was hard to swallow.

**[EDIT]**
OK, prompted by a question from Peter Schor (thank you, Peter), I've continued my research.

The main point is that "find" is a transitive verb and it must be provided with a clear/recognizable direct object.

The "one thing" in front of the verb is confusing the situation, as it can be taken to be that direct object.

Let's separate the antecedents from the verb, by using an "and." Now at Google Books we find:

["and find it hard to understand"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and%20find%20it%20hard%20to%20understand%22%20&ei=3fwTVcuoINKzogSKxYEY#tbm=bks&q=%22and%20find%20it%20hard%20to%20understand%22)

About 4,360 results

["and find hard to understand"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and%20find%20it%20hard%20to%20understand%22%20&ei=3fwTVcuoINKzogSKxYEY#tbm=bks&q=%22and%20find%20hard%20to%20understand%22)

About 84 results

We can conclude here that an long infinitive such as "to understand" is not seen by "find" as a clear-enough direct object, and that "it" becomes necessary, which I believe is coded in some grammar books/rules.

Now, what happens when "one/the thing" pops in right in front of "I found," thus in the proximity of the verb?

Well, as shown by the examples in the above, if what follows "hard" is a clear short infinitive phrase such as "to swallow" "one thing" is taken as the verbal object, and the need for "it" disappears. Other examples:

"One thing I found hard to believe"
"the one thing I found hard to give up—the ocean"

However, if what follows "hard" is a complicated infinitive phrase such as "to be generous about Cornelia's mother never offered me anything to eat", it seems that the native speakers feel the need to switch the focus after "find," "one thing" becomes negligible as a direct object and "it" becomes necessary.

I believe this is a matter of subjective judgement, which the native speakers perform on the fly — thus the variation.

This is the best I could come up with for now.

Comment: What exactly is the difference in meanings? I'll agree that *"it"* is needed in the first example, and cannot be used in the second example, but I'd call that grammar. In the OP's sentence *"One thing I found it hard to get used to doing ..."*, I don't see any difference in meaning with or without *"it"*.

Comment: @Peter Schor. OK, I've tried to answer your question here in the final part of the answer. Pls check after "EDIT". Best.